# You can now report employer messages or block entire companies from further contacting you on Jobs

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, reporting-companies

Stack Overflow always puts developers first. We work very closely with our employers so that they offer the most relevant and meaningful job listings possible. We have strong policies in place that prohibit employers from submitting fake listings and engaging in recruiter spam. We think this makes Stack Overflow the best place to help you build your career. And that is why...

**We're introducing a new feature that allows our users to report employer messages on Jobs, should they contain any suspicious, inappropriate, or spammy content. In addition to that, the existing blocking feature will now extend the block to the whole company whoever you're blocking works for, and not just for that single person who contacted you.**

To go along with these new features, we're putting some new articles on our help center, to provide instructions on how to do these actions. You can find instructions on how to report employer messages [in this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reporting-companies), and on how to block companies from messaging you [in this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/blocking-companies) (which also explains how unblocking works). Note that you'll also be able to report messages directly from emails you receive, and on mobile.

**Wait, but what exactly constitutes "suspicious, inappropriate, or spammy content?" Maybe you should make that clearer first.**

We're also clarifying what fake listings and recruiter spam means. To that effect, we're adding a couple more help center articles that aim to define those two concepts. [**Fake job listings**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-a-fake-job-listing), to put it shortly, are listings published with no intention of hiring for the specified role. A non-targeted, disruptive job listing, message, or job board content, on the other hand, is what we consider [**recruiter spam**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-recruiter-spam).
"Suspicious" refers to content that makes it look like the employer account might have been hacked, for instance. There will also be an option in the report dialogue for that:

[image]

---

You can leave any feedback you might have as an answer to this post. If you stumble upon any bugs, please report them using the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs), and [reporting-companies](/questions/tagged/reporting-companies) tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com repeatedly shows me recruiter spam, as per your definition. Currently, it wants me to move to Germany, learn German and learn Wordpress - a tag I have zero participation in and know nothing about. This is obviously a non-targeted, disruptive job listing. It contains irrelevant content for high visibility (show this to as many as possible no matter who they are). How do I flag https://stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: @Lundin via an ad blocker. Ghostery does a wonderful job for me :)

Comment: @CalvT븃 I believe he is talking about those that are sent in emails, as `We really like this job for you`. I have received unrelated emails like this as well.

Comment: @Lundin Just trying to debug here: in which context did you see this German job, was it in job ads in the sidebar of SO questions, or in an email? (If so, what was the title of the email?) "show this to as many as possible no matter who they are" is pretty much the opposite of what we're trying to do, so knowing more about your use-case is helpful.

Comment: This is still not putting developers first.  You will put developers first when you allow the developers to "review" job listings for people who have worked at a company.  You already have this info so I don't see the issue.

Comment: @JonH: I'm not sure what you are asking. You can see other listings posted by an organization on their ["company page"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/ucla-health), but that doesn't sound like it's the infromation you want.

Comment: @AurélienGasser In the sidebar. It has been pointed out numerous times that these adverts are most of the time highly irrelevant. Real life anecdote: I was once hiring programmers through a recruiting firm and they thought I should advertise the available position. We would get an advert on SO among other things. I turned it down since I knew from experience that those adverts are crap - plus we did not want our company to come across as spammers.