# Is "High Response Rate" for jobs being exploited?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I have been browsing developer jobs and applied to one just now designated with a "High response rate"

[image]

Okay, great, someone on the other end is *actually* looking at applicants and responding at what I assume to be is an above abysmal rate. But, after applying, and after receiving the expected "Success!" email - I then subsequently received a "Reply" from said listing with regurgitated garbage.

This is blatantly automated and I have a problem with it. I have now immediately lost all faith in placing any value in this "high response" accolade.

Is this a current or past issue? Are a few bad apples to blame here, or?

Comment: Could you clarify what "regurgitated garbage" means in this context? Text generated by a Markov chain? A form email with your name in it? Is your problem with them having an autoreply at all, or the fact it gets them the badge?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this... if that's the case, it's something we'd love to know about and deal... accordingly :)

Please [report the employer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356422/you-can-now-report-employer-messages-or-block-entire-companies-from-further-cont) on that particular message. Choose "Something else" and explain what you see wrong with the employer message.

We don't tolerate [recruiter spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-recruiter-spam), so please make sure to report this (and any other spammy message). We don't want to become that place where you get tens of totally garbage messages per day.

We do want employers to provide feedback (even if it's automatic) when they've made an offer (we understand that's a better candidate experience than never hearing back). However, sending an automatic message right away just to game the system... that's definitely wrong.

**UPDATE:** In this particular instance, the customer has set up an email address to receive applications. They receive applications from Stack Overflow but potentially, from other sources as well.

When they do, they send back an autoreply confirming the reception of the application, which is a nice thing to do if you're doing so via email.

I'm working on tweaking our badges logic so that it doesn't take into consideration replies that are too fast for the badge.

**UPDATE 2:** The logic to award badges has been tweaked. 51 company pages and 65 jobs lost their "High response rate" badge thanks to this change.

Comment: I'm extremely impressed at the ~6 hour turnaround time on this. Thank you!

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ that's a... high response rate!

Comment: That gave an entire new meaning to ~2 - 4 weeks....

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ but how do you know it was actually him and not an automated response to something they had already fixed and were just waiting for someone to report to make it look like they have a super great turnaround time? An investigation is warranted!